# the type or namespace name 'dll Name' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) asp.net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CIgp.png)I Have Asp.Net Website version 2.0 .My Project Contain Some dll File based Some Work.Its Work fine.I Search QRCode Generate Project and i get One project from http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-generate-and-display-QR-code-Image-in-ASPNet.aspx this link download this project and i open this project in VS2005 and Run it But i get Error 'the type or namespace name 'QRCode.dll' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)' and i leave it this project.After that Compile My all Web project i get same Error in all my Project.But dll name different QRCode.dll Replace my project dll.What happend and What Solution...thanks to all...

Answer (score 1):

Extract the "QRCoder.dll" library from `QRCode.zip`(located in the `bin` folder) and add it to your project.

1. Extract the DLL
2. In VS, right click on "References"
3. Select "Add reference"
4. Browse to the file and click "Add"

Comment: i dont want QRcode project..i want run my project but my project not working bacause this error "The type or namespace name 'dll Name' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) "

Comment: Then why is there a link in your question to that project? Anyway, you can fix this error by adding the missing dll (QR or otherwise) as shown in my answer, or remove all the references and code depending on that dll from your project.

Comment: Are they also present in the `bin` folder where the website is running?

Comment: And did you add `using xxxx.dll;` to the page? You can do this by clicking `Control + .` when you are on the marked error. VS will add it to the page

Comment: You added `using DAL;` to the page, but as the error shows, the DLL is missing or `DAL` is an incorrect `NameSpace`

Comment: 'DAL' is  my own creation dll file.its include in bin...last 5 years its working this project same dll and this project run in another system.same project Copy and paste another system run perfect...and also same project folder run IIS ....

Comment: The last thing I can think of is that there is a mismatch in the FrameWork versions. Check if all Libaries and projects use the same version.

Comment: project property window add Reference button i click and add dll file not added in project.